# Calling functions between components Angular2

Tags: angular, components

I have a question concerning calling functions between components in Angular 2:

In my navigation component (`navigation.component.ts`) I have button, which calls a function: `dispenseIfAbreise(){}`

I `@Output` this function via an EventEmitter:

```
this.abreisenExport.emit();
@Output()abreisenExport:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

In my `tischplan.component.html` file I emit the function `abreisenRemoval()` with this code:

```
(abreisenExport)="abreisenRemoval($event)
```

Then in the called function `abreisenRemoval($event)`in the `departments.component.ts` (`Parentcomponent`) file I call another function from a `Childcomponent`:

```
@ViewChild(DepartmentsComponent)
private departmentsComponent: DepartmentsComponent;

abreisenRemoval() {
    this.departmentsComponent.occupy();
}
```

The function called in the `Childcomponent` emits another event besides calling the service, which calls the backend: `this.updateImHausListeElement.emit();`

In the html file the function is emitted:

```
(updateImHausListeElement)="updateImHausListeElement($event);"
```

which is in the `tischplan.component.ts` (`Parentcomponent`) file:

In the `updateImHausListeElement(){}` function another function is called which is again in a `ChildComponent: imHausListeComponent`

```
@ViewChild(ImHausListeComponent private imHausListeComponent: ImHausListeComponent;


updateImHausListeElement() {
    this.imHausListeComponent.updateImHausListeElement();
}
```

In summary I emit a function call from my `NavigationComponent` to the `Parentscomponent`, which calls a function in another `Childcomponent`, which again emits a function call to the `Parentscomponent` (Besides a service function call to the backend), which then calls a function in another `Childcomponent`.

So my question is, is this bad practise what I am doing here? There are additional parameters I pass between the functions, which are not relevant to my question I think.

Thanks a lot for the effort.

Comment: Why not use services to prevent a lot of function emitting?

Comment: Yes, I was considering this option. I will update my code. Thank you very much for this comment.

Comment: I agree with @AlexanderPoshtaruk. That is a whole lot of parent to child and child to parent communication to keep track of. From a readability and maintainability perspective it would be much easier to consolidate all that communication to a service, compared to tracking through all these various components and their various functions and events.